# Xcode Haskell Syntax Highlighting

Tags: xcode, haskell, syntax-highlighting

When programming in Haskell, what options are available for syntax highlighting in Xcode? Haskell's website linked to an Xcode plugin, but that link is broken.

Comment: just don't use XCode for Haskell. there are much better alternatives such as Emacs or Leksah or Vim or FPComplete etc.

Comment: I agree, I started with textmate and then moved over to using gvim. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

I did not find an xcode solution, but I found an app called TextMate that handles syntax highlighting for Haskell. I find it to be a powerful IDE so far.